# Rest API Request Param and Path Variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have to invoke a Get service with the below URL. The URL is a mix of Path variable and Request Param. Right now the URL is not getting constructed properly. Any suggestions?

Below is how i have tried and the actual output from Postman.

Sample:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{abc}/commPrefsConsents/fieldOptions")
public ResponseEntity<String> getIndividualApi(@PathVariable(value = "abc") String abc, @RequestParam(required = true) String fieldOptions)
```

Actual URL:

http://localhost:8080/token/ca26e12dcfg-gdhska1/commPrefsConsents/?fieldOptions=preference-basic

URL getting created from Rest Controller :

http://localhost:8080/ca26e12dcfg-gdhska1preference-basic

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate uri would be:

`/ca26e12dcfg-gdhska1/commPrefsConsents/fieldOptions?fieldOptions=preference-basic`

There is also a chance, that the mapping is affected by the `@RequestMapping(value='foo')` on the class level. If so, simply add `foo` to the beginning of your uri call.

Comment: I tried to define the context after the Path Variable and put those in a property file, so that it can be changed outside the code deployment.

Example:
in my application.yml:  hc.app.bu.request_param=/commPrefsConsents/?fieldOptions=preference-basic

Code:
System.out.println("URL :::" + sfmcConfig.getIndividualApi_url() + hcId + sfmcConfig.getRequest_param());